# XQuery Count all Nodes

Tags: xml, xquery

Is there a way to select the sum of all nodes within 1 XML nocument

```
for $c in doc("http://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial.xml")
return count($c//country)
```

That is what i currently have but this only returns the count of all top level nodes.
I would like to count all existing nodes.(recursively?)

Comment: So you want to count all `country` elements in the XML? How about `count(doc("....")//country)`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain the requirement with an example input and output. I find it hard to believe that your requirement is simply to "count all nodes" since that's simply `count(//node())` - unless you want namespaces and attributes as well.

Comment: No that was pretty much what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To count all nodes in this XML document, the following XPath expression suffices:

```
count(doc("http://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial.xml")//node())
```